# Ubuntu 15.1 L2TP with MSCHAP

Tags: vpn, ldap, ipsec

I have a client that wants to use their existing VPN that utilizes L2TP with MSCHAP.. I see that 15.1 does not use OPENSWAN but uses Secure SWAN.

I installed that with *apt-get install strongswan network-manager-strongswan*

I now have the option for VPN -> L2TP but I see no way to enable MSCHAP so it'll authenticate against LDAP/AD.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? Am I missing a config file or something or is it even possible in this latest version of Ubuntu?